# Prevent app from crashing from java.io.IOException: write failed: ENOSPC (No space left on device)

Tags: java, android, ioexception

In an attempt to write to the device, when the device is full, I am getting error:  `com.google.gson.JsonIOException: java.io.IOException: write failed: ENOSPC (No space left on device)`. I have a try-catch block to catch an IOException and a few lines to check the size of the list and storage space available to determine if there is space to write the file but yet it still crashed the app and I got the IOException mentioned above.

Here is the code:

```
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), fileName+".txt");
int file_size = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(file.length()/1024));
long storage_size = (getAvailableInternalMemorySize()/1024);
long list_size = listToWrite.toString().getBytes().length/1024;
long total_size = file_size + list_size;
if(total_size < storage_size) {
    try (Writer writer = new FileWriter(file, false)) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        gson.toJson(listToWrite, writer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to stop the app from crashing and just display a Toast message to the user or perform some action.

Comment: I recommend that you edit your question and provide the complete stack trace.

Comment: I'll have to get that when it throws the error again.

Comment: You should probably allow at least an extra 10% of free space before you can attempt to store anything in the storage. The system will not give away every available byte.

Comment: Good point. Sounds like a good idea. So I'll just find the total storage space and allow for .10 of that before attempting to write.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I went with 1% instead
`double one_percent_internal = .01 * total_internal_size;
        long list_size = listToWrite.toString().getBytes().length/1024;
        long total_size_to_write = file_size + list_size + available_size;
        if(total_size_to_write > one_percent_internal)`

Comment: It would be a good idea to warn the user that they're running low on space and give them a chance to clear some out before storing any more files locally. The system starts to seriously misbehave if it's running so low on storage.

Comment: Yes. I did that with the rest of the if-else block by adding a toast to the user.
I'm using if-else as a check on the storage to prevent a crash but shouldn't the try-catch implementation prevent this? Maybe I'm misinformed about what a try-catch block does.

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute in your manifest file :

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```